# how to design and code in android like the following

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

in my app i have scale and progress bar as shown in the following figure[image]

i have separate image for progress bar and marker. my need is how to make the marker to be movable over the progress bar in android. please help me.

my layout xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/scale_bg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_bg" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_arrow" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ImageButton>
</FrameLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**updated xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/scale_bg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:thumb="@drawable/slider_arrow"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider_bg">
    </SeekBar>


</RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

slider_bg and slider_arrow are png images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do, I suggest you check out the following blog article which does a very good job describing how to do it: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: i refer the site but i get the following error:

Failed to parse file C:\PhysicalTherapy\painscale\res\drawable\seekbar_progress.xml. please help me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:thumb="@drawable/slider_arrow" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider_bg"></SeekBar>
```

Comment: i get the following error in error log

main.xml:java.lang.unsupportedOperation error .please help me.

Comment: where does the error come from? My example works fine over here.

Comment: please see my updated xml in my edited question. and slider_bg and slider_arrow are png images.

Comment: its not comming from the XML file i think.

Answer (score 0):

It's `SeekBar` actually, which is equivalent with `Slider` on Windows controls. You need to customize the background, color and indexer.